# Free alternative to openinig solidwork defualt files in linux( *.sldprt & *.sldasm)?

Tags: cad

I migrated to Linux and don't want to use solidworks , so i need one software which could opening my already solidworks file like *.sldprt and *.sldasm .

So i have installed FREECAD but it could not opening those files.

Another question i have is this:
  could i do my modeling designing which only need to fit dimension and shape without any characteristic simulation and ... in solidworks alternative, and which one is your suggestion?

Thank A lot.

Comment: Could you export the solidworks files to another format that then will work with FREECAD?

Comment: You wont find any tool to open solidworks files that is free. (the problem with properitary files is that its a running target needing a dedicated team to do changes all the time)

Comment: Indeed even older versions of Solidworks can't open newer Solidworks files.

Answer (score 1):

I found one way and that is to use free [online solid-work platform](https://www.solidworks.com/online-product-trials) to change those tile format to desired new format:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you could use an exchange file format such as IGS or STEP and import this file into FreeCAD.
Another option is to use [Onshape](https://www.onshape.com) that lets you import SolidWorks files for free and you could convert it to another file format.

Comment: Onshape is really good. However, you might note that the free access option doesn't allow private files. Thus anyone can view your files.

Comment: @EricS, that's true. But you can do the conversion and then erase the files.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is going online to [onshape.com](https://www.onshape.com).  It is a browser based parametric modelling software.

It has a quite interesting story. It has been developed by [Hirschtick]([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Hirschtick#:~:text=He](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Hirschtick#:%7E:text=He) was a player and,eventually grew to %24600 million.). The same guy that developed Solidworks. Hirsthtick eventually left Solidworks because he had a difference in vision  with Dassault (i.e. the 3d CAD should be working towards the browser - not the workstation). After he left, he started developing Onshape, and a couple of years back, he sold it to PTC that develops *PTC Creo* (a competitor of Solidworks).

I've been working over 10 years with Solidworks and its still my preferred tool of choice. I've also tried a couple of others like Inventor and Creo. However, the transition to Onshape has been the smoothest.

Comment: Onshape is really good. However, you might note that the free access option doesn't allow private files. Thus anyone can view your files.

Comment: yeap, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

If you know anyone that has SolidWorks or someone on this site who offers, you could send them your SLDPRTs and SLDASMs and they could import them and send them back to you as STLs which you can import into FreeCAD.

I might be able to convert them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Edrawings](https://www.edrawingsviewer.com/view-cad-files-free). It is a free lightweight viewer for Solidworks files and assemblies. I had completely forgotten about it until @Eric S mentioned that Onshape files are open to everyone in the free version.

The only problem is that probably there is no option for linux. Unless you use an android emulator and you download the mobile version.